# How to contact Partner Support after the account is expired

Tags: isv, partner

I am trying to reach out the Salesforce partner support to reactivate my account.

But, my partner account was expired.

I've searched and read so many articles and they say the only way to contact Salesforce partner support is throught help.salesforce.com. (ref: [FAQ: New Salesforce Partner Support Experience](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&type=1&id=Salesforce-External-Partner-FAQ-New-Partner-Support-Experience)

However, my account was stopped, I have no way to login for logging a case.

This is really a trouble for me and please help.

In my case, is there a way to reach out the Salesforce's Partner Support?

Answer (score 0):

For account related issues you will need to reach out to the Account Executive.
Unfortunately support cannot reactivate partner account.

Thanks